# Doctrine 2 - Mapping multiple inheritance type from a single Entity

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm

It's possible to set a multiple inheritance type from a single Entity?

I have this Entity

```
namespace Oilproject\ContentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"5" = "ContentAnswer"})
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Table(name="content")
*/
class Content
{
    //My attributes
}
```

and i want to extend this Entity with another Entity but with "JOIN" inheritance type.
It's possible?

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/jyh7fnoXvDs